# Как получить скрин

Tags: c#

Подскажите как получать скрин под нужное разрешение,но и не обрезать в это время скрин?

```
int width = Screen.width;
     int height = Screen.height;
     Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
```

Так картинка получается более 1мб

Comment: Что значит под нужное разрешение?

Comment: @sp7 дело в том, что в данном коде я получаю full скрин,который весит более 1мб - нужно делать по менее объемным

Comment: Дак а с чем связано такое требование в плане размера, по современным меркам 1Мб это не много?

Comment: @sp7 инфы много - 50 человек быстро засрут диск - диск маленький

Comment: Можно рассмотреть вариант с компрессией изображения, но тогда будет потеря качества картинки.

Answer (score 1):

Texture2d.(readpixel,resize, encodetojpg),textureimporter, Texture2d.apply. И готово. Еще можно вариант посмотреть http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/TextureScale

Answer (score 0):

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            g.CopyFromScreen(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y, 0, 0, new Size(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height));
        }
        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
    }
```

В таком случае рамка тоже скринится, так как координаты берутся формы, а не picturebox. Можно банально вычесть рамку.
Если наводить красоту можно сделать picturebox полностью прозрачным:

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.pictureBox1.BackColor  = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb( 
            ((System.Byte)(255)), 
            ((System.Byte)(128)), 
            ((System.Byte)(128)));
        this.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb( 
            ((System.Byte)(255)), 
            ((System.Byte)(128)), 
            ((System.Byte)(128))); 
    }
```

Comment: Я не работаю с формой - скрин делаю на C# движок Unity

Comment: Так бы и написали, что работаете с движком Unity,а не только с C#.